# How to completely remove an unknown superuser password from UEFI (Acer Aspire Switch)

Tags: windows-10, bios, passwords, uefi, acer-aspire

I have an Acer Aspir Switch 10 E or `SW2-016` with Windows 10 and UEFI firmware (V1.15)

Apparently I once upon a time have set a `Supervisor Password` in the `Security` settings. Ofcourse **I forgot it**.

I **am** able to get into the UEFI settings using the <kbd>F2</kbd> key on startup, enter a wrong password three times until I get to the `Enter Unlock Password` option. Then I used [this generator](https://bios-pw.org/) to get a correct and working unlock code.

**But** this procedure is ofcourse quite annoying so my question:

**Do I have any option to remove the `Supervisor Password` entirely without nowing it?**

If I try to unset it via the UEFI itself I have to enter my current password before setting it to nothing ...